# Reflection - Get the size of List<SomeClass>

Tags: java, reflection

Help me deal with reflection. There is a `SuperClass` class and a `SomeClass`:

```java
public class SuperClass {
    private List<SomeClass> listClass;
    
    public SuperClass(){
        this.listClass = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    // ... getter and setter listClass
}

public class SomeClass {}
```

How can I use reflection to get the size of the `listClass` property of the `SuperClass` ? Preferably by calling the `getListClass` method.

Comment: elements in the list.

Comment: Since you indicated that there are getters and setters, why do you want to use Reflection at all? Just call `getListClass().size()`.

Comment: @Holger, because I use different classes with different methods(I mean different method names). The class method call is defined in the json configuration file, such as the application architecture. Perhaps with a different application architecture, I could call methods using `getter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know that it's a List or just a collection, you can use an Iterator.

```
Class<?> objectClass = listClass.getClass(); 
if (Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(objectClass)) {
    int size = ((Collection<?>) listClass).size();
}
```

You could also call the `size()` method via reflection, but there is no good reason to do it.

```
try {
    int size = (int) listClass.getClass().getMethod("size").invoke(listClass);
} catch (NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
    // do something
}
```

If you can, you should just call:

```
listClass.size();
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer helped me a lot.

Comment: Every `Collection` has a `size()` method. So there is no need to be sure that the collection is a `List`. Further, there is no need to use `Class<?> objectClass = listClass.getClass(); … Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(objectClass)`, as an ordinary `listClass instanceof Collection` does already do the job. But since the compile-time type of `listClass` is already `List`, not even that is needed.

Comment: Well, the obvious solution without any reflection is just calling `listClass.size();`.